# Html Css How to remove black rectangle background from image

Tags: html, css

I am getting below mention image [image: image with black rectangle background]

Below is html div which i am using

```
<div class="image-cropper">
                  <img [src]="url" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail">
                </div>
```

Below is css :

```
.image-cropper {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

img {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

How can i clip the black background or make it transparent? Please suggest.

Comment: Some other rules applies black background for `.image-cropper` or to some elements behind it. Simply remove `background-color: ` from it

Comment: Your image contains that black color, you should edit your image.

Comment: @imEnCoded Nope, the OP's CSS would clip of the black area if that was the case...

Comment: Does the `.image-thumbnail` has any styles? Or are there more CSS rules that affect the image or `.image-cropper`. when I test same code with only the CSS you provided it creates round image without the black color.

Comment: It looks like you have some more settings, like a lightgray border around the image with slightly rounded corners and some padding. Where is that coming from? Perhaps that's where the black background is coming from. Your CSS you provided is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have background set to black.

The reason you see parts of your background as black is because the border-radius of the pictures is set to 50%:

If you want to completely remove the black background:

- Remove the background-color: black;

If you want to (as you wrote) want to make background transparent:

- Add background: rgba(0,0,0,0) - where 4th value controls the opacity.

Comment: `opacity: 0;` will result to no visual of that.

Comment: Exactly. Setting opacity: 0; will make background black to be completely not visible.